# how to pass query string with 2 values in mvc

Tags: google-maps, model-view-controller, view

i want to send two values (longitude and latitude)while we click a row. so that when i click a row in table it should redirect to the web page and show marker in google map.how can i pass dynamic values in the query string

code

```
    @model List<smartpond.Models.AssetDetailsViewModel>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Details";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
     <div>
            <table>
            <tbody>
                            @foreach (var device in Model.Select(x => x.deviceid).Distinct().ToList())
                        {
                            foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.deviceid == device).Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
                            {
                                    <tr class="tr_@item.value.deviceid">
                                        <td>@(item.i + 1)</td>
                                        <td>@item.value.deviceid</td>
                                        <td><a href="@Url.Action("Marker", "Tracker")">@item.value.latitude</a></td>
                                        <td><a href="@Url.Action("Marker", "Tracker")">@item.value.longitude</a></td>
                                        <td>@item.value.time</td>
                                        <td>@item.value.battery</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: try this.  <a href="@Url.Action("Marker", "Tracker")?latitude=@item.value.latitude&longitude=@item.value.longitude">Marker</a>

Answer (score 0):

use javascript,

```
$("tr").click(function() {
var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

 var latitude= $.trim(tableData[3]); 
 var longitude= $.trim(tableData[4]));
//3 for latitude and 4 for longitude
//then use ajax to pass parameter to function
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'myWebForm.aspx/GetLatLong',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: { lat: latitude, long: longitude },
dataType: 'json',
success: {},
error: {}
});
```

//it will hit the GetLatLong method in myWebForm.aspx

Comment: with this ajax call we can get the single valued (lat long), i have bunch of lat long values in the table. i need all the lat longs to be send via query string(mvc).